# Rails: How to properly set up the timezone on the production server (EC2 Ubuntu)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, time, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that is in the Oregon region.
When I log in on the server, I see the following:

```
System information as of Wed Apr 13 04:13:49 UTC 2016
```

Current time in NYC: 12:51 PM.

All my rake tasks are set according on the NYC time. I had scheduled a task that will run every morning on 4AM, but after moving to AWS EC2, this tasks is running on midnight.

I tried to set the time zone in the `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

But even after restarting the server the tasks are being launched every midnight, not 4AM.

What should be my next steps here?

Thank you.

Comment: "All my rake tasks are set according on the NYC time. I had scheduled a task that will run every morning on 4AM, but after moving to AWS EC2, this tasks is running on midnight."  What mechanism schedules the task?  cron?  sidekiq?  Something else?

Comment: Yes, the tasks scheduled with CRON (`whenever` gem to be accurate).

Answer (score 1):

A subsequent comment on this issue indicates that the `whenever` gem is used.  The `whenever` policy is to avoid timezone logic, leaving it up to you.  There is, however, [this approach](https://github.com/javan/whenever/pull/239#issuecomment-13622877) to `whenever.rb`:

```
Time.zone = "US/Eastern"

every 1.day, :at => Time.zone.parse('4:30 am').utc do
  command 'echo hello'
end
```

This allows your server to continue to live on UTC time (which your post indicates it does) while your code has its own conception of how to describe specific moments on the clock.  The author indicates he favors this approach, and you can verify it yourself by inspecting the crontab (`crontab -l`) after a deployment.  It's important to note that your crontab *will* be in UTC; this system library has no special knowledge of your Rails environment or runtime.